# iOS Google maps sdk - markers are not pointed while using subview instead of main view

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

Trying to display a simple Google map with a marker at location "position".

If mapview_ is shown in self.view(Default view of controller) instead of gmapsView (subview of self.view) of class GMSMapView then everything is working fine.

I have gone through some of the posts on **SO** but couldn't solve the issue.
in Interface builder gmapsview class is set to GMSMapView.

**Camera Postion setup**

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                                             37.778376,
                                                             -122.409853);
CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:position.latitude longitude:position.longitude];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:position.coordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:position.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:13];
```

**Map setup**

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.gmapsView.frame camera:camera];
mapView_.delegate = self;
self.gmapsView.camera = camera; //gmapsView is a view of class GMSMapView

CGRect rect = self.locationBlockView.frame;

self.gmapsView.delegate = self; //Added to check whether it works
self.gmapsView = mapView_;
```

**Setting up Marker**

```
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position]; //Adding Marker
marker.map = mapView_;
[mapView_ animateToLocation:position.coordinate];
```

Comment: I don't get you Im afraid. what do you want, what works, what doesn't?

Comment: @Daij-Djan 1. Maps and markers are loading in default view. 2.Maps are loaded in the subview but markers are not shown.

Comment: gmapsView is of class "GMSMapView". class is set in the IB and have link in the controller.

Comment: why then do you alloc init a new instance?

Comment: Yes thats the mistake! Initially tried sample code provided by developer.google and later on modified to my need.  
I have just tried removing the instantiation and viola its working. But logically Even though if its re-instantiated it should work right ? In a normal scenario When an UIView is accessed by re-initialized it works why its failing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-Initializing the map was causing the issue. Once it is removed it solved the issue. But Re-initializing GMSMapView is causing the issue ? Its an absurd thing, but it solved the issue.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                                             12.778376,
                                                             -122.409853);
currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:position.latitude longitude:position.longitude];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:eventLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:eventLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:13];
//[self.gmapsView removeFromSuperview];//removing the subview
//self.gmapsView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.gmapsView.frame camera:camera];
//self.gmapsView.delegate = self;

//self.gmapsView = self.gmapsView; //set map

// [self.view addSubview:self.gmapsView];//Adding back did the magic
self.gmapsView.delegate = self; //set delegate
self.gmapsView.camera = camera; //set camera

GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position]; //Adding Marker
marker.map = self.gmapsView;
[self.gmapsView animateToLocation:currentLocation.coordinate];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add Google Map To Subview**

**The Solution Steps**

**1) Change the class of the UIView in the story to GMSMapVIew.**

[image]

**2) Next I created an IBOutlet for the green UIView container and Connected it.**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface CarLocationViewController : UIViewController  
//An outlet of type GMSMapView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapContainerView;
@end
```

**3) Then in my view did load I did the following**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:14];

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = self.mapContainerView;

    //set the camera for the map
    self.mapContainerView.camera = camera;

    self.mapContainerView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

}
```

I am Following This Link http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/ios/obj-c/maps/gmap/subview

Comment: Its now more than a year old question which was answered a year ago and what you are doing in step 1 and step 2 is commented under the question. Are you summarising the whole tutorial from the link? a thought, There was an error in one line and rectifying answered it and **I feel pointing out the error should be an answer!**